# Access to update the user/middleware

Tags: node.js, middleware

I have a simple put method to update the user and i added a middleware(Auth) to check the user  is login or not but i have a problem that Any logged in user can update another users.

I want each user to be able to **update her/his profile only**

```
router.put('/:id', Auth, validateid, async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const NewPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    name: req.body.name
    , email: req.body.email,
    password: NewPassword

  }, { new: true })

  if (!user) return res.status(404).send('Not Found');

  res.status(200).send(user);
})
```

Comment: What is `req.user` that you're setting in the auth middleware?  Is that something you can check against `req.params.id` or against `req.body.name` or against something else in the DB to make sure they're only updating the appropriate profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is compare `req.params.id` (id passed in parameter) and `req.user._id` (id of the user who made this request) initially in the function. Your middleware auth function, after authenticating puts the user's data in req.user (user that made the request). If the two ids are equal that would mean the user who made the call (`req.user._id`) is trying to update their data(`req.params.id`). If they are not equal simply return a error response with 403 (Forbidden) status code.

```
router.put('/:id', Auth, validateid, async (req, res) => {

  if(req.params.id != req.user._id.toString()){
     return res.status(403).send("Forbidden to edit another user");
  }

  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const NewPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    name: req.body.name
    , email: req.body.email,
    password: NewPassword

  }, { new: true })

  if (!user) return res.status(404).send('Not Found');

  res.status(200).send(user);
})
```

Comment: it solved my problem but i got an error ` Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` we should use `return` statement to solve it `if(req.params.id != req.user._id.toString()) return res.status(403).send("Forbidden to edit another user");`